# Is it possible to rollback only nested transaction for autotesting

Tags: .net, sql-server, unit-testing, transactionscope

Consider the following code:

```
ExecuteSQL("UPDATE ...");

using (var t = new TransactionScope())
{
    ExecuteSQL("UPDATE ...");

    if (SomeCondition)
        t.Commit();
    else
        t.Rollback();
}

var result = ExecuteSQL("SELECT ...");
```

Then we write an auto test using outer *TransactionScope* to rollback changes after each test:

```
[TestInitialize]
public override void Initialize()
{
    _transaction = new TransactionScope();
}

[TestCleanup]
public override void Cleanup()
{
    _transaction.Dispose();
}
```

It's not possible to write a correct test for a case when *SomeCondition* is *false*. Because nested transaction ROLLBACK rollbacks the whole outer transaction including the first UPDATE statement.

Do you know any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can rollback to a savepoint, see [Exception Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) but that is not the same as what you want.

What is what you're *really* trying to achieve? Testing should occur under similar conditions to production. Adding an uber transaction and testing methods in inner transactions is nothing like how the system would behave in production.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't really support nested transactions.  It just has one transaction that has seen multiple `start transaction` statements, and requires multiple `commit transaction` statements before it really commits.

As a workaround, don't nest the transactions. It is possible to run two transactions simultaneously on different connections.

Answer (score 0):

Unnamed rollback rolls all thansactions back up to the top of the stack.

The only thing which can help is to use named [SAVE TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx)

**Warning**: Does not work with distributed transactions.

Comment: Are there any TransactionScope wrappers that use SAVE TRANSACTION?

Comment: @alexey Try to pass the command itself to server, without any wrappers

Comment: @alexey ... and notice, that TransactionScope is SERIALIZABLE by default and VERY distribution tran friendly 8-)